# Como ordenar una figura de la clase Graphics - JAVA

Tags: java, jframe

Estoy resolviendo un ejercicio en el cual debo dibujar un rectangulo en un `JFrame`, pero me encontré con un problema.

He dibujado el rectangulo del tamaño de la ventana:

```
this.setSize(400, 300);

g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
```

Al ejecutar el programa, la ventana completa se ve blanca y no se ven los componentes que contiene, como botones y campos de texto.

He logrado identificar que el problema esta en el orden de los componenetes del `JFrame`.
Estos los puedo ordenar con *NetBeans* en la sección *"Design"*, pero no se como se ordena la figura de la clase `Graphics`.

Exactamente esta figura:

```
g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
```

Si en vez de utilizar el metodo `paint`, utilizo el metodo:

```
getContentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

... Me funciona a la perfeccion, pues solo se modifica el fondo de la interfaz, que es lo que quiero; pero en el ejercicio se pide que lo haga con el metodo `paint`.

Creo que seria bueno aclarar esto, es util saber como se ordenan los componentes de un `JFrame`.
Gracias.

PDTA: El metodo `setComponentZOrder()` me sirve para ordonar componentes como `JLabel`, `JButton` o `JTextField` entre otros, pero no permite ordernar otros componentes que no pertenezcan a `JFrame`, como es el caso de `Graphics`, el objeto `g` no lo reconoce como un componente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para los componentes de `swing` lo mas normal es sobre-escribir con `paintComponent`, `paint` es mas para la *GUI* de `awt`, puedes hacer la prueba, por ejemplo, con `Button` o `TextArea` en lugar de sus equivalentes `JButton` o `JTextArea`.

Cuando usas `setBackground` funciona adecuadamente porque en algún punto, cuando se requiere, se hace un llamado a `repaint` y ésta llamada a su vez invoca a `paintComponent` (**quien es realmente el que refresca la *GUI***  `swing`) no a `paint` (**aplica a *AWT*, por eso no se ven los** `JButton`, `JTextArea`, **etc, cuando se refresca la interfaz gráfica**).

Puesto que te es necesario el uso de `paint` entonces lo mas proximo podría ser, en la medida de lo posible, hacer el repintado de los componentes `swing` justo después que se dibuje el rectángulo.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {  
  g.fillRect(0,0,400,300);
  for(int i=0;i<miPanel.getComponentCount();i++) {
    ((JComponent)miPanel.getComponent(i)).repaint();
  }
}
```

Esta solución desde luego no es tan flexible como las llamadas implícitas a `paintComponent` pero hace su trabajo de mantener visible cada componente.

En cuanto al asunto del orden, definitivamente eso no tiene mucho que ver para èste caso en especifico.